# What is this font in the image

Tags: css, html, fonts, webfonts

Hi guys I know this is a silly question, I am struck with a assignment in HTML/CSS everything is good but I am unable to recognize the font, I am new to CSS just a 4-day crash course and still learning, what would be the font in the image below.(the image is a part of assignment)

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It is about font identification.

Comment: I feel it is highly unlikely they will deduct points from your assignment for not getting the correct font unless they have explicitly included in the directions that you should do so.  If they DID include in the instructions that you should match the font, there is probably a better way of identifying it than via an image.  If they asked you to match the font and THEY provided that image, then your professor is a jerk, you should call him out on such hooligans, and demand your money back. Outside of all of that, you can try this URL. http://www.whatfontis.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft's [Segoe UI](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=331). Check out a preview of the same:

[image]

Comment: Can someone let me know why did I get a downvote? Thanks!